# Quartz Spring Test JUnit

Tags: java, spring, junit, quartz

How to use a Job that is operating in Cluster with Spring?

- Spring 4.3
- Quartz 2.2.3

Sample job declaration

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class SysEncryptEmailSendSystemJob implements Job{
..
  @Override
  public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) throws 
    JobExecutionException {
  }
}
```

My Factory IOC

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = SysConfig.SCHEDULER_FACTORY)
private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory;
```

I know I could annotate as @Component but thus lose the functionality of quartz, the goal of doing the IOC is to do the tests with JUnit!

> Any way to do that? has anyone done or doc explaining how to do this?